# Wireless adapter not working

Tags: wireless

I just install ubuntu on my acer Extensa 5420 computer. My computer does have wireless adpater but my computer doesn't show any wireless connections.I have try ubuntu help and i couldn't find anything there.  Can anybody help?

EDIT: Pastebin wireless info [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7936061/)

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7936061/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot

The issue you are having is because the firmware for the driver is missing.